# Node JS - Pusher trigger

Tags: node.js, pusher

The trigger function is not working for me in Node JS.

```
pusher.trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', {"message": "hello world"});
```

I can not se anything in the Debug Console that Pusher is receiving data.
There is no problem from the Debug Console to send a event to my webpage client, the client is using privet channel and i auth against my server. So i know that my params i right. I am using the EU cluster in pusher and i have config it to connect it to the right server.

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');

var pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: '123',
  key: 'foo',
  secret: 'bar',
  encrypted: true
});

pusher.domain = 'api-eu.pusher.com';
pusher.port = 443;

pusher.trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', {
  "message": "hello world"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not realy know way, but this code made it all work.

```
var pusher = new Pusher.forURL(process.env.PUSHER_URL);
```

Comment: `process.env.PUSHER_URL` will contain your Pusher credentials in the form of a URL. I expect that this contains the valid credentials, and in your initial code in the question you were using a different set of credentials that were not valid. Glad you got it working though :)

Comment: THIS was the only thing that worked for me.  Crazy for how long ago you posted this answer, that the issue is still not fixed...